# Como baixar uma fonte para impressora Zebra usando ZPL?

Tags: vb.net, impressora

Estou tentando baixar uma nova fonte para Zebra (GC420t) usando ZPL.
Este é o código que eu uso para este trabalho .:

```
teste + = "~ DYR: OptimaLTStd, B, T, t, w, dados"
```

e para imprimir com fonte:

```
teste + = "^ XA"
teste + = "^ FWB"
teste + = "^ FO290.150"
teste + = "^ A2,36,20, R: OptimaLTStd.FNT"
teste + = "^ FD" & Etiqueta.Quantidade & "Kg ^ FS"
teste + = "^ FO335,90"
teste + = "^ A0,36,20, R: OptimaLTStd.FNT"
teste + = "^ FD Validade:" & Etiqueta.Validade & "^ FS"
teste + = "^ FO380,150"
teste + = "^ A0,36,20, R: OptimaLTStd.FNT"
teste + = "^ FD" & Etiqueta.Lote & "^ FS"
teste + = "^ XZ" 'Gravar o documento
```

O que acontece: essa fonte não foi encontrada e a impressora está usando a fonte padrão

modelo: GC420t